# Asp.net with c# file upload from excel using sql server 08

Tags: sql, asp.net, excel, sql-server-2008, exception

> Exception Details: System.Web.HttpException:
>   'c:/users/agaabhis/documents/visual studio
>   2010/Projects/WebApplication4/WebApplication4/Files/' is a physical
>   path, but a virtual path was expected.

Source Error:

> Line 23:  Line 24:             //Upload and save the file Line 25:
>   string excelPath = Server.MapPath("c://users/agaabhis/documents/visual
>   studio 2010/Projects/WebApplication4/WebApplication4/Files/") +
>   Path.GetFileName(FileUpload1.PostedFile.FileName); Line 26:
>   FileUpload1.SaveAs(excelPath); Line 27:

```
 Source File:  c:\users\agaabhis\documents\visual studio 2010\Projects\WebApplication4\WebApplication4\Default.aspx.cs    Line:  25
```

Comment: A bit more information would be quite helpful, e.g. your source code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you read the documentation for `Server.MapPath` [on msdn](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms524632%28v=vs.90%29.aspx), you'll find that you cannot hand it physical paths (which have a drive as a root). You need to give it paths relative to the server. For example:

```
string excelPath = Server.MapPath("Files/") + ...;
```